# std::function initialization inside class

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I am trying to understand how std::function works and I am not able to compile this and I don't understand why. I think it has something to do with using std::function inside class because without classes (map defined in global scope) it worked.

This is the error message I get:

> functor.cc:37:9: error: could not convert `‘{{"A", ((C*)this)->C::f},
>   {"B", ((C*)this)->C::g}, {"C", ((C*)this)->C::h}}’` from
>   `‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’` to
>   `‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::function<bool(const
>   std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)> >’`

Sample code (it makes no sense but it pretty represents the problem I have):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


class C { 
    public:
        bool f(const std::vector<std::string>& s) {
            std::cout << "F" << std::endl;
            for (auto& i : s) {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            return true;
        }

        bool g(const std::vector<std::string>& s) {
            std::cout << "G" << std::endl;
            for (auto& i : s) {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            return true;
        }

        bool h(const std::vector<std::string>& s) {
            std::cout << "H" << std::endl;
            for (auto& i : s) {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            return true;
        }

        std::map<std::string, std::function<bool(const std::vector<std::string>&)> >  funcMap {
            {"A", f},
            {"B", g},
            {"C", h}
        };
};


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v{"mno", "pqr", "stu"};
    C c;
    c.funcMap["A"](v);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> std::function<bool(const std::vector<std::string>&)
> ```

That function object type can only wrap functions that have the the signature `bool(const std::vector<std::string>&)`. However, none of the functions that try to use have such signature because they are (non-static) member functions. Also, you must use the address-of operator explicitly to get a pointer to a member function and the name must be fully qualified like so: `&C::f`.

You could bind `this` to the member functions which would result in a function object of appropriate signature:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<bool(const std::vector<std::string>&)> >  funcMap {
    {"A", std::bind(&C::f, this, std::placeholders::_1)},
    {"B", std::bind(&C::g, this, std::placeholders::_1)},
    {"C", std::bind(&C::h, this, std::placeholders::_1)}
                           ^ we bind this pointer to the function object
};
```

You can use a lambda as well. Bound functions and lambdas are mostly just two ways to write the same thing.

---

Alternatively you may have intended to in fact store just the member function and not the object pointer in the function object. In that case the type of your function object is wrong as well as the way you call it. This would work:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<bool(C*, const std::vector<std::string>&)> >  funcMap {
//                                       ^ note the pointer argument for this
    {"A", &C::f},
    {"B", &C::g},
    {"C", &C::h}
};

// call
c.funcMap["A"](&c, v);
//              ^ The object on which the member function is called. 
//                It doesn't necessarily have to be the same whose funcMap is used.
```

In this case you don't really need `std::function`. A map of member function pointers would be sufficient. The syntax of calling a member function pointer is a bit different from using a function object:

```
std::map<std::string, bool (C::*)(const std::vector<std::string>&) >  funcMap {
    {"A", &C::f},
    {"B", &C::g},
    {"C", &C::h}
};

// call
(c.*c.funcMap["A"])(v);
```

---

However, it is unclear why you would need to use member functions at all considering none of them use the state of the object. Another simple solution would be to not use non-static functions in the first place.

Comment: Great, it worked. I am still struggling with std::function, std::bind, raw function pointers, named lambda functions and when to use them.

This was just a simple example, I just want to call different functions according to keys in std::map.

Comment: @MichalŠpondr what is a named lambda function?

Comment: Named lambda function:
auto func = [] () { cout << "Hello world"; };
func();
(Why not to use standard function here? And beginner questions like that)

Comment: @MichalŠpondr that is a lambda. Why do you call it "named"? Lambdas are unnamed function objects.

Comment: Because you can use lambda function without assigning into variable func. I don't see the reason why use auto func = [](){}; and use func repeatedly when I can create standard function with same name.